# /etc/shadow in old format, where is salt stored?

Tags: hashing, linux

In /etc/shadow I have entries such as `admin:YtChlvAGYzva2:16318:0:99999:7:::`. I know the original password and would like to generate the same hash somehow. However, running `openssl passwd -crypt password` gives me different results every time I run it. I assume salt is involved, so where can I find the salt used to create the original hash?

**Edit:** I managed to get the original hash using the following command:

```
openssl passwd -crypt -salt Yt password
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The salt and the encrypted password are both mashed into the string YtChlvAGYzva2.

From the [Shadow Password Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-2.html):

> When a user picks or is assigned a password, it is encoded with a
>   randomly generated value called the salt. This means that any
>   particular password could be stored in 4096 different ways. The salt
>   value is then stored with the encoded password.
>
> When a user logs in and supplies a password, the salt is first
>   retrieved from the stored encoded password.

The longer password strings you see with modern systems [separate the hash using $](http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/etcshadow-format/).  But for the older systems, it was just mashed in ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))):

> Earlier versions of Unix used a password file (/etc/passwd) to store
>   the hashes of salted passwords (passwords prefixed with two-character
>   random salts). In these older versions of Unix, the salt was also
>   stored in the passwd file (as cleartext) together with the hash of the
>   salted password.

In your example, I believe that the salt is "Yt" and the encrypted password is "ChlvAGYzva2".  It's literally the first two characters of the string.

Comment: Can I separate them somehow?

Comment: @JohnEye Use the substring methods of your favorite script/language?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the original hash using `openssl passwd -crypt -salt Yu password`.

Comment: @schroeder: I asked this before OP changed the post :-)

Comment: And... what was the salt? First two characters (Yt) of the hash as stated by gowenfawr?

Comment: Aside from `openssl`, the following python one-liner will also do: `python -c 'import crypt;print(crypt.crypt("toor","X0"))'` where `X0` is the salt.